# R - Read Matrix Data from file with free spaces

Tags: r, matrix

I have an map of efficiency data as matrix stored in a text file. With increasing row number data points are missing at the end of the line since there are no data available. When I try to read the data as matrix in R:

```
mymatrix = as.matrix(read.table(file="~/Desktop/Map_.txt"))
```

I get the error message that the row 3 (in this case the first row with missing values at the rows end) has not all values expected.
Is there a way to read the map file as matrix even with free spaces (no values) in some lines?
Thank you!

example:

```
    1000  2000  3000  4000  5000
-1    85    75    65    60    58
-2    86    74    64    58    52
-3    83    78    68    59
-4    86    80    72    
-5    86    81    71
```

Comment: Of course, you have to tell `read.table` which are missing values through the `NA.strings` argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I'll check that out...

Comment: If your missing cells are always in the rightmost columns, you may also want to set `fill=TRUE`.

Comment: ok, i just can't find the answer myself. using`mymatrix = as.matrix(read.table(file="~/Desktop/Map.txt"), na.strings = "" )`still doesn't work...